# Laravel can't access Vendor folder?

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I'm just getting started with learning Laravel, and I want to create a form with a WYSIWYG editor, so I use

```
https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor
```

I have run the terminal command, and included the script (`.js` file )
I have added the id to my editor, but it doesn't work.

I try to inspect element, it says that it can't find the `.js` file in the vendor folder. I guess it's because the vendor folder is not in the public folder ?

FYI, I set my MAMP ( local server ) with direct access to the public folder.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't work. You should have a `vendor` folder in you public folder that contains the resources

Comment: Yes i have a folder and it contain the resource , but on my browser ( Chrome ) my form still just a plain form not CKeditor and on inspect element it say that it can't find the JS file . which is actually there in vendor folder

Answer (score 0):

So actually i do the publish command before i include the JS
and i dont know why it doesn't copy the vendor folder to public folder

so i try to run the command again

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor
```

and now it copied to public folder and it works !